# How to redirect url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Hello I need to redirect from a url like this:
https://www.domain.com/folder1/

to

https://www.domain.com/folder1/file.html

how can I do this on an htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryIndex file.html` to set the new folder index.